# How to update multiple foreign key references when you change a table name in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that needs a name change, but there are many references to this table.  When I run the following query

> USE information_schema; SELECT * FROM KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE
>   REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME' and CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'TEST_SCHEMA'

there are more than 50 results.  Is there a way to update these all at once or do I need to write an alter script for each reference?  I'm using mysql and the table is innodb.  It has to be able to be run through db deploy so I won't be able to use an admin login (trying to update KEY_COLUMN_USAGE fails).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started out creating the new table like the old table to preserve the hibernate references for the rest of the team while my changes weren't, then when my foreign keys caused my tests to fail I thought it was going to be something I'd have to do manually.  The alter table command updates this like it should and all is well!

Answer (score 0):

To update a FK is necesary to exists a PK, that's not negotiable.

- You can delete the FK and recreate it.
- Or you can try setting `auto_commit=0;` do all your queries (first the PK and then the FK) and make a commit.

take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/commit.html)